# IONIC ngFor recovering data from firebase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

This code works until the the passageiro.ts  controller, that print on console the array above.

The fact is that the view loops an empty item.  Am I doing anything wrong?

```
(2) [Object, Object]
0 : Object
id : "jMi0U0qT5yO1y04AyLynnQAJEvl1"
nome:"Test1"
__proto__ : Object
1 : Object
id : "v88qudbTpqeDcXWNHpqz0rOzZe92"
nome : "Test2"
```

---

Service

```
getPassageirosList(){
  let passageirosReturn = fb.database().ref('users');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      passageirosReturn.orderByChild("tipo_usuario").equalTo("passageiro").on('value', snapshot => {
      let passageiros = [];
      snapshot.forEach( snap => {
      passageiros.push({nome: snap.val().username,id: snap.key});
      return false;
    })
    resolve(passageiros);
  });
});
```

---

Controller

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.passageirosService.getPassageirosList().then( passageiros => {this.passageiros = passageiros; console.log(this.passageiros)});
}
```

---

View

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let passageiro of passageiros">
      <h2>{‌{pasageiro?.id}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: For.what is this `return false;` in `forEach`?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you might want to check that you have the passagerios list before showing it.
Might not be the answer, but try adding a *ngIf to your list.

```
<ion-list *ngIf="passageiros">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let passageiro of passageiros">
    <h2>{‌{pasageiro?.id}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```